# Disable IPv6 in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose project that I am trying to run on my server, which does not have IPv6 enabled. Whenever I try to run the container, I get the following error message:
`nginx: [emerg] socket() [::]:80 failed (97: Address family not supported by protocol)`

I figured that is because IPv6 is not enabled on my server (it is managed by a third party, so I can't touch that), so I tried disabling IPv6 for docker-compose, so far without any luck.

I tried adding

```
sysctls:
      net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6: 1
```

on my config file, but then I received the following error
`Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6: no such file or directory: unknown`

How can I disable IPv6 in docker-compose, either for this particular container or system-wide to not have issues like this?

This is my current config

```
        container_name: cont-nginx
        networks:
            - cont
        image: nginx:latest
        depends_on:
            - cont-app
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "880:880"
            - "4443:4443"
        sysctls:
            - net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
        volumes:
            - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

networks:
    cont:
        driver:  bridge
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disabling IPv6 for the docker's network should do the job:

```
networks:
    cont:
        driver:  bridge
        enable_ipv6: false
```

Also, maybe you should consider removing this from your nginx conf

```
listen [::]:80;
```

because **[::]** is for IPv6.